# content script not being injected into extension html page

Tags: json, content-script

I have an extension that gets JSON data from a site for a list of characters and their resources when chosen from a menu. I'm using a single html page and trying to update it with javscript to modify the code for the menu. The only thing is that I can't get the content script injected/loaded into the html page.

When my extension is run, the path for the rem.htm file is shown as 'moz-extension://a02e52b1-e41d-4d28-844b-a8466a1dd67b/rem.htm' which gives an invalid error for the 'matches' key in the console.

What else can I use?

manifest.json:

```html
{
  "description": "Resource Manager for Path of Exile",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Path of Exile Resource Manager",
  "version": "1.0",
  
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["file:///rem.htm"],
      "js": ["modify-page.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background":
  {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon":
    {
      "16": "icons/rem_16.png",
      "32": "icons/rem_32.png",
      "64": "icons/rem_64.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions":
  [
    "*://www.pathofexile.com/",
    "webRequest",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't realize I had modify-page in a separate directory. I was then able to add '' to matches and it finally worked!